# Extract Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest Post URL from shortcode

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract URL of Facebook / Twitter / Pinterest from shortcode which I put in my blog content using PHP's Regular Expression . The shortcode takes the following form like,

`[embed type="facebook"]https://www.facebook.com/Techzoom.TV/posts/1960179340843049[/embed]`

`[embed type="Twitter"]https://twitter.com/HelloBdWorld/status/1568289461284524033[/embed]`

I am not familiar with RegEx. But, I played with it a little and came with the pattern, like:

`preg_match('/(\[embed\stype\=\"[facebook]+\"\]).*(\[\/embed\])/i', '[embed type="facebook"]https://www.facebook.com/Techzoom.TV/posts/1960179340843049[/embed]', $socialOccurrences);`

The output that I get, is:

`Array ( [0] => [embed type="facebook"]https://www.facebook.com/Techzoom.TV/posts/1960179340843049[/embed] [1] => [embed type="facebook"] [2] => [/embed] )`

But, it's not giving me the URL (https://www.facebook.com/Techzoom.TV/posts/1960179340843049).

Can anyone help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through your example:

1. If you want an URL you should [capture it inside the group](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Captures.html#:%7E:text=Captures%20represents%20a%20group%20of,available%20via%20the%20name%20method.).
2. The `[facebook]+` means "a single character in the list facebok between 1 and unlimited times". If you want to match the whole word - you need to wrap in in group as well.

So your fixed solution might be like this:

`/\[embed type="(?:facebook|twitter|pinterest)"\](.*)\[\/embed\]/ig`

This way you declare 2 groups - the website name (`facebook`, `Twitter`, ...) and the URL. Since you need only the URL, I assumed the former group [might be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions).

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Ricjfq/1